# Different order of first names and last names in footnote and in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, footnotes

I'm using BiblaTeX with `giveninits=true` and `\footfullcite` to add footnotes. I've set

```
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
```

and it's correct for "Bibliography" page but is not correct for footnotes. In footnote should be `given-family`.

Bibliography should looks like that:

> Ford R.

But footnote should looks like that:

> R. Ford

Is it possible to set different order for footnotes?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}

\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newtxmath, newtxtext}

\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
    @book{ford,
        title       = "Twitter Users Learned of Tremors Seconds Before Feeling Them",
        author      = "Rebecca Ford",
        year        = "2011",
        location    = "Northampton"
    }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[
    style=authortitle,
    sorting=nty,
    language=polish,
    sortlocale=pl_PL,
    giveninits=true
]{biblatex}                                
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}

\begin{document}

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    Integer nec varius tellus \footfullcite{ford}.

    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `authoryear`- and `authortitle`-based bibliography styles the primary name list associated with an entry (usually the `author` or `editor`) is formatted in the name format `sortname`. So changing `default` will have no effect on the author in the bibliography in your example. `\footfullcite` locally resets `sortname` to `default` so that a change to default will affect the footnote citation.

For a change to the bibliography you would need

```
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
```

(the difference is only visible if there are two names or more).

So a simple solution would be

```
\documentclass[a4paper, polish, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[
  style=authortitle,
  sorting=nty,
  giveninits=true,
  uniquename=init,
]{biblatex}                                

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
  \null\vfill % just for the example to push the text down to the footnote

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  Integer nec varius tellus \footfullcite{sigfridsson}.

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Bibliography: Sigfridsson E. i Ryde U.//Footnote: E. Sigfridsson i U. Ryde.]

Note that I used `babel` and not `polski.sty`. That way `biblatex` can pick up all language settings automatically.

Comment: I spent so much time on it, and it turned out to be so simple... Thanks!